# Put files automatically in folders

Tags: sorting, batch-file, directory, bulk

I have thousands of JPGs named like this "aaa0001.jpg, aaa0002.jpg, aaa0003.jpg,
bbb0001.jpg, bbb0002.jpg, bbb0003.jpg, ccc0001.jpg, ccc0002.jpg, ccc0003.jpg etc." in one folder.

I have created 26 folders like this aaa, bbb, ccc, ddd etc.

Is it possible to create a script that sets all the images in the appropriate folder?

Result "aaa0001.jpg, aaa0002.jpg, aaa0003.jpg" into folder "aaa", 
"bbb0001.jpg, bbb0002.jpg, bbb0003.jpg" into folder "bbb" etc.

Thank you!

My system is windows XP prof SP3...

Comment: Of course its possible! Which system? Which script language...

Comment: Sure. Write some code to parse out the path element from the filename.

Comment: My system is windows XP prof SP3...

Answer (score 2):

It would go like this in a Windows/dos batch file.

The statement `%fp:~0,3%` determines which part of the filename is used as a foldername. 0,3 means: from the first character and the next 3 chars.
so a file named `aaa001-01.jpg` will give a folder of `aaa`.
To have files named `abc001_03.jpg` go into folder `001` you change the statement to `%fp:~3,3%`

```
for %%a in (*.jpg) do call :copyfile %%a
goto :eof

:copyfile
set fp=%1
set folder=%fp:~0,3%

rem remove echo on the next line...
echo copy "%1" "%folder%"
rem or for moving:   move /Y "%1" "%folder%"

goto :eof
```

Comment: I think i need another example to understood: How does it work with files named like this: abc001_01, abc001_02, abc001_03 etc. - i want to put them in a folder named 001?

Comment: You only asked about aaa/bbb/ccc etc. Edit your question to clarify what you need to do.

Comment: Sorry, does not work for me...

It opens a DOS windows and all the file are running.

But the everything is untouched...

Comment: did you remove 'echo'? The text after echo will get executed, echo is there for debug purpose

Comment: OK, i have removed echo. Now it works, but it creates copies of the files and put them into the folders...

Comment: for files named like this: `abc001_01` replace `set folder=%fp:~0,3%` with `set folder=%fp:~3,3%` (take char 3, 4 and 5 instead of char 0, 1 and 2)

Answer (score 0):

Just define the base path to create the news directorys in the VAR `$path`

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

:::The path where the new Directorys will bw created

set $path="c:\Image\"

for %%a in (*.jpg) do (set $file="%%a"
                       set $Dir="%$path%CSV!$file:~4,3!"
                       if not exist "!$dir!" md "!$dir!"
                       move "!$file!" "!$dir!")

echo Terminated
```