# Batch file put folders into other folders depending on name

Tags: batch-file

A very similar question to this has been asked ([Put files automatically in folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20328665/put-files-automatically-in-folders)) however I am struggling to convert the answer in the aforementioned question to suit my needs.

My problem is that I need to move folders into other folders using a section of their name, the question that was answered before was about moving files.

My folders have date and time stamps on them `2016-08-23 15.23.45`. I need to move these folders to another folder that has just the date on them `2016-08-23`.

As another small request, since I'm not very skilled with windows batch files, could someone please tell me where I will need to put my file paths into the batch file.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please note that https://stackoverflow.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @DavidPostill `'I am struggling to convert the answer in the aforementioned question to suit my needs.'` Did you notice the question/ answer they refered to in their own question? What makes you think they didn't try that?

Comment: @BorisSmith I am aware of that. He doesn't tell us "and where you are stuck". In addition, neither of the answers in the link question are really suitable for conversion to solve this problem.

Comment: @DavidPostill If neither of them are suitable then I don't even know where to begin. I know that the other file works by getting the name of each file and then putting it in a folder that matches the first 3 characters of the original file. I need this functionality but instead of a file it must be a folder. I do not know how to make it be for folders instead of files which should be 100% clear with my question

Comment: I'm feeling generous today. I have taken time to write a custom batch file for you. See my answer.

Comment: @BorisSmith, actually I do not consider link-only questions as good questions, just like link-only answers, because links may become invalid in future, even if they point to another post on this site...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### I need to move folders into other folders using a section of their name

> My folders have date and time stamps on them `2016-08-23 15.23.45`. I need to move these folders to another folder that has just the date on them `2016-08-23`

Use the following batch file (test.cmd):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=1,2" %%d in ('dir /a:d /b') do (
  if not exist %%d md %%d
  if [%%e] neq [] move "%%d %%e" %%d >nul 2>&1
  )
endlocal
```

Example usage:

```
F:\test>dir /a:d /b /s
F:\test\2016-08-23 15.23.45
F:\test\2016-08-23 15.23.46
F:\test\2016-08-23 15.23.47
F:\test\2016-08-23 15.23.48

F:\test>test

F:\test>dir /a:d /b /s
F:\test\2016-08-23
F:\test\2016-08-23\2016-08-23 15.23.45
F:\test\2016-08-23\2016-08-23 15.23.46
F:\test\2016-08-23\2016-08-23 15.23.47
F:\test\2016-08-23\2016-08-23 15.23.48

F:\test>
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) - Loop command against the results of another command.
- [dir](http://ss64.com/nt/dir.html) - Display a list of files and subfolders.
- [if](http://ss64.com/nt/if.html) - Conditionally perform a command.
- [md](http://ss64.com/nt/md.html) - Make Directory - Creates a new folder.
- [move](http://ss64.com/nt/move.html) - Move a file from one folder to another.
- [redirection](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) - Redirection operators.