# Batch to create folder and move files with first 9 characters matching

Tags: batch-file

I am just wondering if I have modified the source and target location appropriately on using code posted in answer on [How to copy files into folders based on first 15 characters of file and folder name?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40830807/3074564)

I can't get it to run. I am just trying to create a folder named the first 9 characters and move all files with matching first 9 characters into that folder.

```
@echo off 
setlocal EnableExtensions 
set "SourceFolder=C:\PRASINUS\July #2" 
set "TargetFolder=C:\PRASINUS\Test 1"

rem Call subroutine CopyFile for each non hidden and 
rem non system file found in specified source folder 
rem and then exit processing of this batch file.

for %%I in ("%SourceFolder%*") do call :CopyFile "%%~fI"

endlocal 
goto :EOF

rem This is a subroutine called for each file in source folder. 
rem It takes the first 9 characters from each file name passed 
rem to this subroutine via first parameter and search for a 
rem folder in target folder starting with same 9 characters. 
rem If such a folder is found, the file is copied to this folder 
rem and the subroutine is exited. 
rem Otherwise a new folder is created for the file and if 
rem this is indeed successful, the file is copied into the 
rem newly created folder with an appropriate message.

:CopyFile 
set "FileName=%~n1" 
set "DirectoryName=%FileName:~0,9%" 
for /D %%D in ("%TargetFolder%\%DirectoryName%*") do ( 
    copy /B /Y %1 /B "%%~D\" >nul 
    goto :EOF
)

set "NewFolder=%TargetFolder%\%DirectoryName%_new" 
md "%NewFolder%" 
if exist "%NewFolder%\" ( 
    echo Created new folder: %NewFolder% 
    copy /B /Y %1 /B "%NewFolder%\" >nul 
    goto :EOF 
)

echo Failed to create folder: %NewFolder%
echo Could not copy file: %1 
goto :EOF
```

Comment: Sorry mate first time user.

Answer (score 3):

Code formatting: cut-and-paste your code;select it and press `{}` in the bar above the edit-box to indent each line 4 spaces (which indicates 'code')

You need to include `\` between `%SourceFolder%` and `*` in `"%SourceFolder%*"` to indicate to `cmd` that you want all files (`*`) within the directory `%SourceFolder%`, not files matching "%SourceFolder%+*anystring*"

The `directoryname` variable is set correctly (*but* are you worried about names shorter than 9 characters?)

You then appear to want to check on the presence of any directory starting `%directoryname%` and copy the filename found to the first such name found; if no directory found, create a new one; check it was created and either copy or notify as appropriate.

All of which appears OK. If this is intended to have a target on a FAT-formatted drive however, you should be aware that the directorynames are not necessarily returned in alphabetical order, so `directory_old` may appear before `directory_new` if both exist.

I must congratulate you on the amount of documentation you've used. It's my preference to use `::` in place of `rem` as I find it makes for easier reading - you're not "reading" the `rem` "word" as the eye ignores the `::` since it's not a word. Note that `::-comments` may not be used within a code-block (parenthesised series of statements)

Comment: Thanks Magoo,

I am still not getting any output or error messages.
All the files are 9 characters or more long

example of the data in the source folder
110236296 (2).pdf
110236296.jpg
110236296.pdf
110236346 (2).pdf
110236346.jpg
110236346.pdf

I am expecting two folders in this case named 110236296 & 110236346
with 3 files in each. all saved in the target folder.

Any ideas why i am getting nothing?

Comment: Worked perfectly for me with those filenames once the "\" has been inserted. If you insert `echo ` before the `md` and `copy` statements, you should get a console-report of what the script intends to do. If you then remove the `echo` before the `md` run again, the new destination directories should be created and the `copy` instructions reported. As I say, it works quite happily for me...

Comment: @Magoo Thanks about the comments I wrote for the batch code posted at [How to copy files into folders based on first 15 characters of file and folder name?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40830807/3074564) which Naith Bryen copied without referencing the source and with modifying it to a not working version because of removing the backslash character between `%SourceFolder%` and `*`.

Comment: @NaithBryen Well, you have to additionally remove `_new` from batch code to get folders with the names `110236296` and `110236346`.

Comment: @Mofi Ooh - claiming authorship by failing to cite the original work - and making modifications that break the code into the bargain. Very naughty. OP should slap his wrists (note slap, not slash). We'll assume he was unaware of the protocol and is now appropriately chastened. Next time though - trip to the headmaster's study. Padding certain areas with a sturdy book advised.

Comment: Sorry lads, first time on here. I definitely couldn't write anything that complex on my own. I'll be sure to reference the source next time.

Comment: I strongly advice against the practice of use `::` instead of `REM` command. This is a strange trick that works for the same reason that other most standard "comments" could be used, like `://`, or `:'`, or `:#` and a long et cetera... This trick was first used more than 35 years ago in order to speed up the execution of Batch files from floppy disks! See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16632524/what-does-double-colon-mean-in-dos-batch-files)

Comment: @Aacini: So - `cmd` regards it a a label hence it can't be used in a code block as I said. Terminating a line with a caret - well, I've never used that construct and don't advocate its use. `::` was used in the DOS days as a dummy argument to permit a batch to change its behaviour - %3*somecommand* would skip the command if `%3` was a double-colon for instance. I've no recollection of any speed-up realised, but floppies was a long time ago... I've not seen any of the other potential broken-label constructs being used for comments.

Comment: I only say that the advice of use `::` to beginners is not a good idea...

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to the example script you found, *(minimum requirement Windows Vista)*:

```bat
@Echo Off 

Set "SRC=C:\PRASINUS\July #2"
Set "DST=C:\PRASINUS\Test 1"

SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
If Not Exist "%SRC%\" (Exit/B) Else If Not Exist "%DST%\" Exit/B
For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('Where "%SRC%":?????????*.*') Do (Set "FNX=%%~nA"
    If Not Exist "%DST%\!FNX:~,9!\" (MD "%DST%\!FNX:~,9!" 2>Nul
        If ErrorLevel 1 Echo Unable to create directory %DST%\!FNX:~,9!)
    If Exist "%DST%\!FNX:~,9!\" (Move /Y "%%A" "%DST%\!FNX:~,9!">Nul 2>&1
        If ErrorLevel 1 Echo Unable to move %%A to %DST%\!FNX:~,9!))
Timeout -1
Exit/B
```

The above is for the first nine characters as requested. To change to fifteen characters replace each instance of `9` with `15` and match the quantity of sequential `?`'s to `15` too.

Answer (score 0):

All help with this goes to @XionicFire he reworked the whole of this code I'm just posting it for others to use/benefit:

This code comes from a mix of several different people @PrahladDixit & @Compo, the code was not working we couldn't tell why after a LOT of search seems it suffered the usual... "a pro wrote this so no one understands what he did" syndrome, where us worms cannot figure it out, we remade it and organized it so normal human "worms" can understand what its doing and made it a little friendlier so its easier to mod and change as needed, we hope this helps others, works great in windows 11

```
@ECHO OFF
ECHO This file will create Individual folders inside the current folder using the following Parameters and sort all *.JPG files in current directory accordingly
REM To change target or source directory simply type it in the variable field
SET "SRC=%~dp0"
SET "SRC=%SRC:~0,-1%"
SET "DST=%~dp0"
SET "DST=%DST:~0,-1%"
ECHO. 
REM For Diagnostics & Troubleshooting Purposes
ECHO Source: %SRC%
ECHO Destination: %DST%
ECHO Characters: 19
ECHO Where: %SystemRoot%\System32\where.exe "%SRC%":*.jpg
ECHO. 
ECHO To Cancel this operation press CTRL-C
PAUSE
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
If Not Exist "%SRC%\" (Exit/B) Else If Not Exist "%DST%\" Exit/B
For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\where.exe "%SRC%":*.jpg') Do (
    SET "FNX=%%~nA"
REM Replace 19 for the number of characters from the start of the filename you wish to use as Base for folder creation
    SET "FNX=!FNX:~,19!
REM For Diagnostics & Troubleshooting Purposes
REM ECHO !DST!\!FNX!\
    If Not Exist "!DST!\!FNX!\" (MD "!DST!\!FNX!" 2>NUL
        If ErrorLevel 1 ECHO Unable to create directory !DST!\!FNX!)
    If Exist "!DST!\!FNX!\" (MOVE /Y "%%A" "!DST!\!FNX!">NUL 2>&1
        If ErrorLevel 1 ECHO Unable to move %%A to !DST!\!FNX!)
    )
ECHO ************************ DONE ************************
PAUSE
REM Use in the case of running multiple scripts in a row
REM EXIT/B
```